# Search and sort through dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to sort and search through a dictionary. I know that dictionary cannot be sorted. But all I need to do search through it in a sorted format. The dictionary itself is not needed to be sorted.

There are 2 values. A string, which is a key and associated with the key is an integer value. I need to get a sorted representation based on the integer. I can get that with OrderedDict.

But instead of the whole dictionary I need to print just the top 50 values. And I need to extract some of the keys using RegEx. Say all the keys starting with 'a' and of 5 length.

On a side note can someone tell me how to print in a good format in python? Like:

```
{'secondly': 2, 
'pardon': 6, 
'saves': 1, 
'knelt': 1}
```

insdead of a single line. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) to pretty-print a dictionary across multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the dictionary based on the integer value you can do the following.

```
d = {'secondly': 2, 'pardon': 6, 'saves': 1, 'knelt': 1}
a = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

The `a` will contain a list of tuples:

```
[('pardon', 6), ('secondly', 2), ('saves', 1), ('knelt', 1)]
```

Which you can limit to a top 50 by using `a[:50]` and then search through the keys, with youre search pattern.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways to get a sorted dict, `sorted` and `iteritems()`are your friends.

```
data = {'secondly': 2, 'pardon': 6, 'saves': 1, 'knelt': 1}
```

The pattern I use most is:

```
key = sorted(data.iteritems())
print key   #[('knelt', 1), ('pardon', 6), ('saves', 1), ('secondly', 2)]

key_desc = sorted(data.iteritems(), reverse=True)
print key_desc #[('secondly', 2), ('saves', 1), ('pardon', 6), ('knelt', 1)]
```

To sort on the value and not the key you need to override sorted's key function.

```
value = sorted(data.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
print value #[('saves', 1), ('knelt', 1), ('secondly', 2), ('pardon', 6)]

value_desc = sorted(data.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
print value_desc #[('pardon', 6), ('secondly', 2), ('saves', 1), ('knelt', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using OrderedDict already, you can probably do what you need with a list comprehension. Something like:

```
[ value for value in d.values()[:50] if re.match('regex', value) ]
```

Please post your current code if you need something more specific.

For the multi-line pretty print, use `pprint` with the optional `width` parameter if needed:

```
In [1]: import pprint
In [2]: d = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b' }
In [4]: pprint.pprint(d)
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
In [6]: pprint.pprint(d,width=20)
{'a': 'a',
 'b': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For nice formatting check out the [pprint module](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html).

If I'm understanding correctly, an `OrderedDict` isn't really what you want. `OrderedDict`s remember the order in which keys were added; they don't track the values. You could get what you want using generators to transform the initial data:

```
import re, operator
thedict = {'secondly':2, 'pardon':6, ....}
pat = re.compile('^a....$') # or whatever
top50 = sorted(((k,v) for (k,v) in thedict.iteritems() if pat.match(k)), reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:50]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could sort though they keys of the dicionary :

```
dict = {'secondly': 2, 
        'pardon': 6, 
        'saves': 1, 
        'knelt': 1}

for key in sorted(dict.keys()): 
    print dict[key]
```

This will sort your output based on the keys.(in your case the string values alphabetically)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different tools that can help you:

- The `sorted` function takes an iterable and iterates through the elements in order. So you could say something like `for key, value in d.iteritems()`.
- The `filter` function takes an iterable and a function, and returns only those elements for which the function evaluates to `True`. So, for instance, `filter(lambda x: your_condition(x), d.iteritems())` would give you a list of key-value tuples, which you could then sort through as above. (In Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator, which is even better.)
- Generator expressions let you combine all of the above into one. For instance, if you only care about the values, you could write `(value for key, value in sorted(d.iteritems()) if condition)`, which would return an iterator.