# How to search through dictionaries?

Tags: python, search, dictionary

I'm new to Python dictionaries. I'm making a simple program that has a dictionary that includes four names as keys and the respective ages as values. What I'm trying to do is that if the user enters the a name, the program checks if it's in the dictionary and if it is, it should show the information about that name.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    people = {
        "Austin" : 25,
        "Martin" : 30,
        "Fred" : 21,
        "Saul" : 50,
    }

    entry = input("Write the name of the person whose age you'd like to know, or write 'ALL' to see all names and ages: ")
    if entry == "ALL":
        for key, value in people.items():
            print ("Name: " + key)
            print ("Age: " + str(value) + "\n")
    elif people.insert(entry) == True:
                print ("It works")

main()
```

I tried searching through the dictionary using `.index()` as I know it's used in lists but it didn't work. I also tried checking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456233/search-and-sort-through-dictionary-in-python) but I didn't find it useful.

I need to know if there is any function that can do this.

Comment: Why do you need a function ? people[entry]

Comment: You can look up a value in python dict using this syntax: dict[key] which will raise a KeyError if the key is not in the dict e.g. people['Austin'] or you can use the method get(key) which will return None if the key is not in the dict e.g. people.get("Austin")

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to know if `key` is a key in `people`, you can simply use the expression `key in people`, as in:

```
if key in people:
```

And to test if it is *not* a key in `people`:

```
if key not in people:
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple enough

```
if entry in people:
    print ("Name: " + entry)
    print ("Age: " + str(people[entry]) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reference the values directly. For example:

```
>>> people = {
... "Austun": 25,
... "Martin": 30}
>>> people["Austun"]
```

Or you can use `people.get(<Some Person>, <value if not found>)`.

Answer (score 3):

Python also support enumerate to loop over the dict.

```
for index, key in enumerate(people):
    print index, key, people[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3    

people = {
    'guilherme': 20,
    'spike': 5
}

entry = input("Write the name of the person whose age you'd like to know, or write 'ALL' to see all names and ages: ")

if entry == 'ALL':
    for key in people.keys():
        print ('Name: {} Age: {}'.format(key, people[key]))

if entry in people:
    print ('{} has {} years old.'.format(entry, people[entry]))
else:
    # you can to create a new registry or show error warning message here.
    print('Not found {}.'.format(entry))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of all of the answers here, why not:

```
try:
    age = people[person_name]
except KeyError:
    print('{0} is not in dictionary.'.format(person_name))
```

The canonical way to test if something is in a dictionary in Python is to try to access it and handle the failure -- [It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EAFP)](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution:

```
people = {"Austin" : 25,"Martin" : 30,"Fred" : 21,"Saul" : 50,}

entry =raw_input ("Write the name of the person whose age you'd like 
to know, or write 'ALL' to see all names and ages: ")

if entry == 'ALL':

    for key in people.keys():
        print(people[key])

else:

    if entry in people:
        print(people[entry])
```