# Working with a dictionary with list as values and a bit confused on accessing

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

So I am working on an IRC chat server and I have a function in which I am trying to allow users to join a channel or list of channels with a JOIN command and create those channels if they don't exist.  I also was trying to implement a PART command that has a similar structure and parameters but will remove a user from the list if and when it finds them in the list.  I have figured out how to do that with dictionaries rather than lists which has lowered the complexity of my code but one part that is difficult to figure out is how to check the list value of the dictionary for the reasons listed above.

As a small side note, if I can figure out how to iterate through the inner value dictionary list, I feel like I can handle the errors of the PART command well enough.  These would include if a user tries to PART from a channel they are not in, or part from a channel that doesn't exist.

```
def join(client, user, channelNameList):
    with lock:
        for channelName in channelNameList:
            if channels[channelName] != None:
                #need some way to check through the dictionary values which
                #are a list of strings containing users
                channels[channelName].append(user)
            else:
                createChannel(channelName, user)
```

This is the current function I'm working with.  To clear up a few things, the client is the socket address of the client for sending error codes or replies, the only ones of these are in the createChannel() function so client is not very important for this example.  The user is the current user string that made the call, and the channelNameList is a list of one or more channels that the user is trying to join.  These channels may or may not exist, and must be dealt with in both situations.  The "channels" is the dictionary that all threads in this program have access to which is why I assumed the lock was necessary to avoid read and write errors.  The key of that list is the name of the channel and the values are a list comprising of the topic of that channel in the first index followed by all of the users in that channel.

I don't know if I'm just overlooking something but I'm almost certain this function will allow me to add the same user the same channel multiple times and another conditional check is probably needed right before I choose to append the user to the channel.  This check would be used to see if the user is already a value within the list of values in the current dictionary given by the channelName from the proposed channelNameList.

UPDATE:

```
def join(client, user, channelNameList):
    with lock:
        for channelName in channelNameList:
            if channelName in channels:
                if any(x == user for x in channels[channelName]) == True:
                    pass
                else:
                    channels[channelName].append(user)
            else:
                createChannel(channelName, user)
```

So I feel like I found somewhat of a solution.  It is hard for me to test at the moment but I would like a suggestion on a better solution that allows me for more interaction with the values of the dictionary like a for loop of some kind that checks all the list values in the current dictionary in question.  The reason for this is if my current solution works, I've realized it doesn't solve my next issue which is my PART command which would follow almost exactly the same logic but when I found that the user is in a channel that exists then I should remove them.  This obviously would require individual access to these values, and I just cannot seem to find any examples involving the syntax for dealing with lists with a key value pair of string, list in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search through dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228345/how-to-search-through-dictionaries)

Comment: @ScottHunter unfortunately it doesn't really help me understand getting the info from my value list

Comment: I was wondering if i might have to for each accurate key found I will have to assign the inner list to a temporary list somehow in order to navigate it.  I may try this next, but something tells me this might be unnecessary and there has to be a simpler solution im not seeing

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question for your next issue.