# Searching a Dictionary with values to return values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My app is called elementary. The idea is that chemistry is annoying. You need to operate with C, or carbon, or 12.011, or 6. Each of these pieces of info is unique to the element in question(carbon for example).

I have a dictionary file that my program searches through. Info for each element in the dictionary is displayed like this: "carbon": {"carbon", "C", "6", "12.011"}. I was working to make sure my main file could read the dictionary. I am able to search via key

WHAT I want to do, and where i am STUCK right now is: I want to search by the values through the dictionary. A list should then be made out of the values that were not searched. Carbon should return: C, 6, and 12.011. Entering C should return Carbon, 6, and 12.011

i have code now, but its pretty basic. I would really appreciate a little advice and guidance on how to approach this, if I am approaching this right.

after getting a list, i can start working with breaking it down so other functions can work with the items on the list to put them into the GUI, and search for images based off entry(based off entry 1 of 4 images will post)

this is what i have so far that i am able to search keys with:

```
from periodicTable import elements
var = input("please enter an element, and I will enter the info for it:")
print(elements[var])
```

this is the structure of my dictionary file. I have all the elements from the periodic table, so i dont want to post the whole list

```
elements = {
    'hydrogen': {'hydrogen', 'H', '1', '1.0080'}, 
    'helium': {'helium', 'He', '2', '4.0026'},  
    'lithium': {'lithium', 'Li', '3', '7.0'}, 
    'beryllium': {'beryllium', 'Be',  '4', '9.0121'}, 
    'boron': {'boron', 'B', '5', '10.81'}
}
```

**EDIT:**
i was able to intergrate Ajays code, what i was toying with just before that was this:

```
aNumerical = {
    1: {'hydrogen', 'H', '1', '1.0080'}, 
    2: {'helium', 'He', '2', '4.0026'},  
    3: {'lithium', 'Li', '3', '7.0'}, 
    4: {'beryllium', 'Be',  '4', '9.0121'}, 
    5: {'boron', 'B', '5', '10.81'}, 
    6: {'carbon', 'C', '6', '12.011'}, 
}
```

setting the keys to numbers, then i was going to iterate through to check each key for a matching value. Was this close to working?

```
givenInfo = input("please enter an the information you were given about the element, and I will enter the info for it:")
index = 1
result = []
while index <= 118:
    if givenInfo in aNumerical.items():
        result = list(aNumerical)
        break
    else:
        index += 1
print(result)
```

Comment: May I suggest two things: 1) Share the code  2)  Always return the **same** answer for Carbon, so `"carbon", "C", "6", "12.011"`, no matter what the search item was ("C", or "6", or "Carbon" or "12.011").  That way other function always have the same "start" parameter value.

Comment: i added what I have so far. Currently I am building out the GUI and testing how to search my dictionary file

Comment: Any reason you can't just import the dictionary file..?

Comment: i thought from periodicTable import elements did that. I was looking through a number of ways and that line was the one that worked

Comment: This might get you started: [How to search through dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228345/how-to-search-through-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the dictionary items and then check if  the search term exists in any of the dictionary item.

```
elements = {
    'hydrogen': {'hydrogen', 'H', '1', '1.0080'}, 
    'helium': {'helium', 'He', '2', '4.0026'},  
    'lithium': {'lithium', 'Li', '3', '7.0'}, 
    'beryllium': {'beryllium', 'Be',  '4', '9.0121'}, 
    'boron': {'boron', 'B', '5', '10.81'}
}

search_value = "B"
result  = []
for element, element_dict in elements.items():    
    if (search_value in element_dict):
        result = list(element_dict)
        break
```

Result

```
['10.81', 'boron', '5', 'B']
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments the order of results is not the same as defined in the input.  This is because a dictionary without key value pair will behave like a set.
To fix this the values can be maintained as

```
'boron': ['boron', 'B', '5', '10.81']
```

Comment: As you can see the [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order) changes order  (From: `'boron', 'B', '5', '10.81'`, To: `'10.81', 'boron', '5', 'B'`).  So maybe it's better to define it as: `'boron': {'Name':'boron', 'Letter':'B', 'Number':'5', 'Weight':'10.81'}`  (But I am not experienced in python, or chemics )

Comment: The order of dictionary cannot be determined  unless using OrderedDict. Other ways to preserve order is to use array instead of dict like 'boron': ['boron', 'B', '5', '10.81']. The same code would work in this case

Comment: That why I say (I meant to say) (to [Ian Schaak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19036231/ian-schaak):   "Add a name to the elements"

Comment: i appreciate the help. From here I will be working to get the list broken down and set to its proper values, also bringed my tkinter frame together. Trying to transfer the aesthetic over from custom tkinter to look more modern

Comment: im making sense of the for loop. to me it reads: for (new variable made in for loop), (not sure what element_dict's role is) in (dictionary elements, but .items() designates just the values). I dont understand ",element_dict" being in there.

Comment: a dictionary consists of key and value, When we loop over items of a dictionary we are looping over key and value. In this case  element corresponds to key (boron) and element_dict corresponds to value ({'boron', 'B', '5', '10.81'}). You can put print statements inside loop to understand more

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = {
    'hydrogen': {'hydrogen', 'H', '1', '1.0080'}, 
    'helium': {'helium', 'He', '2', '4.0026'},  
    'lithium': {'lithium', 'Li', '3', '7.0'}, 
    'beryllium': {'beryllium', 'Be',  '4', '9.0121'}, 
    'boron': {'boron', 'B', '5', '10.81'}
}

def search_element(s):
   for index3, key3 in enumerate(elements):
      for i in elements[key3]:
         if (i==s):
            return key3  

s='10.81'
found=search_element(s)
print("The value " + s + " is found with element:" + found)
s='4'
found=search_element(s)
print("The value " + s + " is found with element: " + found)
```

This will return:

```
The value 10.81 is found with element: boron
The value 4 is found with element: beryllium
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: create a look-up table where `"C"` --> `{'carbon', '12.011', '6'}` and so on.

```py
elements = {
    "hydrogen": {"hydrogen", "H", "1", "1.0080"},
    "helium": {"helium", "He", "2", "4.0026"},
    "lithium": {"lithium", "Li", "3", "7.0"},
    "beryllium": {"beryllium", "Be", "4", "9.0121"},
    "boron": {"boron", "B", "5", "10.81"},
    "carbon": {"carbon", "C", "6", "12.011"},
}

# Create a lookup table from the above
table = {}
for values in elements.values():
    for value in values:
        table[value] = values - {value}

target = input("Please enter an element, and I will enter the info for it: ")
info = table.get(target, f"No information on {target}")
print(info)
```

Here are a few interactions:

```bash
Please enter an element, and I will enter the info for it: C
{'carbon', '12.011', '6'}
```

```bash
Please enter an element, and I will enter the info for it: helium
{'He', '4.0026', '2'}
```

```bash
Please enter an element, and I will enter the info for it: Ag
No information on Ag
```

FYI, `table` looks like this:

```py
{
 '1': {'hydrogen', 'H', '1.0080'},
 '1.0080': {'hydrogen', 'H', '1'},
 '10.81': {'B', '5', 'boron'},
 '12.011': {'C', 'carbon', '6'},
 '2': {'4.0026', 'helium', 'He'},
 '3': {'7.0', 'lithium', 'Li'},
 '4': {'beryllium', '9.0121', 'Be'},
 '4.0026': {'2', 'helium', 'He'},
 '5': {'B', '10.81', 'boron'},
 '6': {'C', 'carbon', '12.011'},
 '7.0': {'lithium', '3', 'Li'},
 '9.0121': {'beryllium', '4', 'Be'},
 'B': {'5', '10.81', 'boron'},
 'Be': {'beryllium', '4', '9.0121'},
 'C': {'carbon', '12.011', '6'},
 'H': {'hydrogen', '1', '1.0080'},
 'He': {'4.0026', 'helium', '2'},
 'Li': {'7.0', 'lithium', '3'},
 'beryllium': {'Be', '4', '9.0121'},
 'boron': {'B', '5', '10.81'},
 'carbon': {'C', '12.011', '6'},
 'helium': {'4.0026', '2', 'He'},
 'hydrogen': {'H', '1', '1.0080'},
 'lithium': {'7.0', '3', 'Li'}
}
```